# ifnum not evaluating a variable properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, 3d

I'm trying to create an ifnum statement to draw several line segments and, the last one, must be a different style. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\let\oldvec\vec
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{comment}
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{myblue}{black!40!blue}
\colorlet{myred}{black!40!red}

\providecommand{\sin}{} \renewcommand{\sin}{\hspace{2pt}\mathrm{sen}}

\begin{document}

% Adaptado de: https://wiki.physik.uzh.ch/cms/latex:tikz:electromagnetic_wave
% Electromagnetic wave - colored
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=(-15:1.0), y=(90:1.0), z=(-150:1.0), % rotações/distorções nos eixos, na forma polar
                    line cap=round, line join=round,
                    axis/.style={black, thick,->},
                    vector/.style={>=stealth,->}]
  \large
  \def\A{2} % Amplitude
  \def\nNodes{5} % Número de semi-ciclos
  \def\nVectorsPerNode{8} % Quantidade de vetores por semi-ciclo
  \def\N{\nNodes*40} % Quantidade de pontos a serem calculados para cada semi-ciclo
  \def\xmax{\nNodes*pi/2*1.01} % Valor máximo do eixo x
  \pgfmathsetmacro\nVectors{(\nVectorsPerNode+1)*\nNodes}

\def\drawXaxis{
  \ifnum \value{\iOffset}=\value{\nNodes - 1}
    \draw[axis, red] ({(\iOffset)*pi/2},0,0) -- ({(\iOffset+1)*pi/2},0,0);
  \else
    \draw[thick, red] ({(\iOffset)*pi/2},0,0) -- ({(\iOffset+1)*pi/2},0,0);
  \fi
}

% Desenha os eixos principais
  %\draw (\xmax,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
  %\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- ++(\xmax*1.1,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[axis] (0,-\A*1.4,0) -- (0,\A*1.4,0) node[right] {$y$};
  \draw[axis] (0,0,-\A*1.4) -- (0,0,\A*1.4) node[above left] {$z$};

  \draw[axis] (\xmax+4 , -\A*1.4 , 0) -- (\xmax+4 , \A*1.4 , 0) node[right] {$y$};
  \draw[axis] (\xmax+4 , 0 , -\A*1.4) -- (\xmax+4 , 0 , \A*1.4) node[above left] {$z$};


\def\iOffset{0}
\drawXaxis
\def\iOffset{2}
\drawXaxis
\def\iOffset{4}
\drawXaxis

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem is, it never is able to detect when `\iOffset} = \nNodes - 1` and the drawing is always in the style of the last segment. The segments in question are red. This is the result:
[image]

This first two shouldn't have an arrow, just the last one.
Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Without the \ifnum, the loop works properly, but it just shows one style.

EDIT:

Thanks a lot Steven B. Segletes!

So, I managed to add that to my code, which revolves around drawin the axis above the wave or below. Like this:

```
\foreach \iNode [evaluate={\iOffset=\iNode-1;}] in {1,...,\nNodes}{
    \ifodd\iNode \drawENode \drawXaxis
    \else        \drawXaxis \drawENode
    \fi
}
```

However, with the \drawXaxis like this:

```
\def\drawXaxis{
  \ifnum \iOffset=\numexpr\nNodes - 1\relax
    \draw[axis] ({(\iOffset)*pi/2},0,0) -- ({(\iOffset+1)*pi/2},0,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \else
    \draw[thick] ({(\iOffset)*pi/2},0,0) -- ({(\iOffset+1)*pi/2},0,0);
  \fi
}
```

I get this result, with the arrow on the first segment:
[image]

If I change \drawXaxis to:

```
\def\drawXaxis{
  \ifnum \iNode=\numexpr\nNodes\relax
    \draw[axis] ({(\iOffset)*pi/2},0,0) -- ({(\iOffset+1)*pi/2},0,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \else
    \draw[thick] ({(\iOffset)*pi/2},0,0) -- ({(\iOffset+1)*pi/2},0,0);
  \fi
}
```

I get the image the way I want to:
[image]

Why is that?

I tried "debugging" it, by creating a loop:

```
\foreach \iNode [evaluate={\iOffset=\iNode-1;}] in {1,...,\nNodes}{$\iNode | \iOffset |$}
```

Which gave me: 1|0.0|2|1.0|3|2.0|4|3.0|5|4.0|
I noticed that \iOffset has changed, to at least have a decimal place, whereas \nNodes was an integer. Is it a float now?
I don't understand how the `\ifnum \iOffset=\numexpr\nNodes - 1\relax` managed to say that 0.0 is equal to 4.

Comment: You need `evaluate={\iOffset={int(\iNode-1)}}`. It is a "sin" not because of the e but because of the rest. Use e.g. `\DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{sen}` and if you *really* need to `\DeclareMathOperator{\sin}{sen}` after undermining `\sin` but I would strongly advise to do the former and to use `\sen` when you want to get the `sen` function.

Comment: The redefinition of `\sin` is wrong: it should be `\renewcommand{\sin}{\operatorname{sen}}`. And it's *correct* to redefine `\sin`: you're denoting the sine function, just with a different symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\value` is not what you want.  It works on counters, which your expression does not contain.  To perform the required integer math, use `\numexpr...\relax`.

Please see comments below for additional warnings/disclaimers.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\let\oldvec\vec
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{comment}
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{myblue}{black!40!blue}
\colorlet{myred}{black!40!red}

\providecommand{\sin}{} \renewcommand{\sin}{\hspace{2pt}\mathrm{sen}}

\begin{document}

% Adaptado de: https://wiki.physik.uzh.ch/cms/latex:tikz:electromagnetic_wave
% Electromagnetic wave - colored
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=(-15:1.0), y=(90:1.0), z=(-150:1.0), % rotações/distorções nos eixos, na forma polar
                    line cap=round, line join=round,
                    axis/.style={black, thick,->},
                    vector/.style={>=stealth,->}]
  \large
  \def\A{2} % Amplitude
  \def\nNodes{5} % Número de semi-ciclos
  \def\nVectorsPerNode{8} % Quantidade de vetores por semi-ciclo
  \def\N{\nNodes*40} % Quantidade de pontos a serem calculados para cada semi-ciclo
  \def\xmax{\nNodes*pi/2*1.01} % Valor máximo do eixo x
  \pgfmathsetmacro\nVectors{(\nVectorsPerNode+1)*\nNodes}

\def\drawXaxis{
  \ifnum \iOffset=\numexpr\nNodes - 1\relax
    \draw[axis, red] ({(\iOffset)*pi/2},0,0) -- ({(\iOffset+1)*pi/2},0,0);
  \else
    \draw[thick, red] ({(\iOffset)*pi/2},0,0) -- ({(\iOffset+1)*pi/2},0,0);
  \fi
}

% Desenha os eixos principais
  %\draw (\xmax,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
  %\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- ++(\xmax*1.1,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[axis] (0,-\A*1.4,0) -- (0,\A*1.4,0) node[right] {$y$};
  \draw[axis] (0,0,-\A*1.4) -- (0,0,\A*1.4) node[above left] {$z$};

  \draw[axis] (\xmax+4 , -\A*1.4 , 0) -- (\xmax+4 , \A*1.4 , 0) node[right] {$y$};
  \draw[axis] (\xmax+4 , 0 , -\A*1.4) -- (\xmax+4 , 0 , \A*1.4) node[above left] {$z$};


\def\iOffset{0}
\drawXaxis
\def\iOffset{2}
\drawXaxis
\def\iOffset{4}
\drawXaxis

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 but please do not propagate the redefinition of `\sin` (which I think is a sin) any further. There are many more off-topic thingies like `\let\oldvec\vec` and `\usepackage{comment}`, which is not used here, but they are relatively unimportant. You could also mention to the OP that this is not an orthographic projection, which they could get easily with the `perspective` library, say.

Comment: Now, about the comments from @Schrödinger'scat:

The redefinition of \sin to \sen is because in Brazil, we use the term sen instead of sin, for this trigonometric function. Searching online, this is the way I found to do it, instead of having to write \mathrm all the time. Why do you think this is a sin? Loved the pun, btw :)

About the ```\let\oldvec\vec```, I really don't remember why it's there. Maybe it's already from the code I copied online and didn't bother removing. Why is it so bad?

Comment: Also: About the ```\usepackage{comment}```, I have used it before to comment large sections of code in order to test.

And I wasn't aware of the ```perspective``` library, I couldn't find it on CTAN. I have just been using tikz and pgf to plot functions.